# Problems with literal constants

Tags: c, embedded, c-preprocessor

I am using the Hi-Tech C compiler to program a PIC16F876. I am at a point where I must use a delay, the duration of which is different every time the program runs.

I would like to the the function

```
__delay_us()
```

However,

This function only takes in, as stated in the manual; "Literal Constant" arguments. I had thought that, after calculating the duration of the delay => duration I could use:

```
__delay_us(D);
```

As long as D was assigned like so:

```
#define D duration  //where duration is an unsigned long
```

However, method doesn't work. It seems that when ever I use #define, if the value I am assigning is variable the compiler throws an error?? (I would not expect this, I would have thought the current value of the variable would be made into a constant at the time of assignment..)

If I assign an actual number e.g:

```
#define D 20
```

This works fine, But I want to be able to change the value of D.

I can guess why this isn't working though: The Hi-tech C compiler cant generate assembly code for the delay unless it knows exactly what it is (at compiler time).

I can't use a loop with, for example a 1us delay in it, because the time it takes to step through the loop changes the delay (I need it be be very a accurate).

Is my only option to write an assembly function and pass the value of duration into it?

Comment: You have any finite number of delays in your design? I mean say 1sec, 5sec, 20 sec.. and not other than this. Like that you have any finite list of delays? If so you can write a function like this `void delay_user_defined(int delay) {

 switch(delay) {
  case 1: __delay_us(1); break;
  case 2: __delay_us(2); break;
  case 3: __delay_us(3); break;
  case 4: __delay_us(4); break;
  default: __delay_us(0); break;
 }
}
`

Comment: I can have, I can make them very quickly, but, as stated, If I call multiple things (often inside a loop) then, (because C is very inefficient) It adds a lot to my delay time. I need about 1us accuracy and just using a for loop takes several us's.

Comment: I have edited my comment and check if the example program suits your requirement.

Comment: What you try to do and is the `delay_us()` way the best solution? Normally you shouldn't be dependent of such _critical_ macros

Comment: Sorry, I understand what you mean now. In this system there is the possibility for many differing delays, far more than could be handled using a switch case statement.

Comment: What is the properly problem you want to solve? You try to get the correct timing with `delay_us`, but aren't there better ways to solve the root problem

Comment: The problem I have is: I need to be able to delay accurately from around .1s to 10us. I need to calculate this delay and implement it with very little extra delay (caused by using embedded C)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your controller has low frequency (~10 MHz) then it will not be accurate (as you stated) and reliable to depend on delay function written in C.

You **should use assembly** code to get appropriate delay.

At assembly level, you can fine tune the delay as you will know the time required (the machine cycles and number of T states required) per instruction. You can also find the same in the datasheet of your controller.

Depending on the compiler you can insert the assembly code snippet in your C program using `#asm - #endasm` directives or `asm` keyword, or any other way specified in the compiler manual.

P.S. : I have worked on microcontrollers, I know how difficult it gets when you need to provide a 1 microsec ON pulse to LCD.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice. I'm using a PIC with a 20MHz clock so I think I will have to go ahead and use in line assembly. #notgoingtoenjoythis